# Is there a way to get user input when running a script on a Linux terminal?

Tags: kernel, scripting, linux

I have access to a node of a Linux cluster, on which Mathematica is installed.  However, I do not have access to a Linux GUI.

Typically I write and test Mathematica scripts on my Windows personal computer (with the typical GUI/front end).  Then, I run the scripts on the Linux terminal because the terminal is significantly faster than my desktop computer (my scripts read and write a *lot* of data).  I use the command:

```
math < test.txt
```

where `test.txt` is a text file containing Mathematica code.  I have been using this command successfully to run my scripts.  I just always need to make sure that I do not try to print graphics to the screen, since I don't have a Linux GUI.

However, now I would like to write a script that prompts the user for input.  For example, this code works fine on the Windows GUI:

Print["start"];
str = InputString[];
Print["string: " <> str];
Print["finish"];

But, it fails on the Linux terminal, generating this console output:

> Mathematica 7.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit)
>   Copyright 1988-2008 Wolfram Research, Inc.
>
> In[1]:= start
>
> In[2]:= ?
>
> In[3]:= finish
>
> In[4]:=

Is there any way I can prompt the user for input on a Linux terminal?  The input does not necessarily need to be interactive.  For example, I can imagine there being a way to pass an input string to `math` by a command like:

```
math -input "This is my input string." < test.txt
```

but I am not sure what is the syntax to do this.

**Addendum:**

`InputString[]` works on the terminal if I simply **enter** a terminal using the command:

```
math
```

and then type `InputString[]` in the input prompt.  However, this is *not* how I want to run my scripts, since this (I think) would require me to retype **every** command, line by line.

Comment: @b.gatessucks `math -initfile test.txt` works, but it seems that `math -script test.txt` does not.  For me (Mathematica 7), `math -script test.txt` just gives me a Mathematica input prompt, but does not execute the commands in `test.txt`.  I wonder what is the difference between `-initfile` and `-script`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks `man math` says that `-initfile` "Execute[s] the commands in the initialization file file during startup."  I don't see `-script` described in `man math`.

Comment: -script may be new (?) -- it is not documented in the linux man page for v8 but it is in the GUI help. The significant difference is -script exits when done, while -initfile leaves you at a prompt (unless you Quit[] in the script of course )

Comment: @george2079 Thanks.  OK, I will just use `-initfile`, and put `Quit[]` at the bottom of my scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:
math -initfile test.txt

30

Answer (score 4):

If you need more interactivity, take a look at [mash](http://ai.eecs.umich.edu/people/dreeves/mash/). From the README:

> This is how "math -script" should work. Namely, the same way that the
>   perl/python/ruby/etc interpreters do:
>
> - take a mathematica source file as its first argument
>     (or from stdin if no arguments),
> - make all the arguments available to the mathematica code as an 
>     array (list) called ARGV,
> - evaluate the code,
> - prints to stdout and stderr only what it is explicitly told to.
>
> The advantages of this include having a self-contained mathematica program that
>   can be executed (with arguments) from the command line, and be used with other 
>   programs in a pipeline, etc.

I haven't used it recently but tried it under an older Mathematica version (7 maybe?). Disadvantage is that you need perl (which should be no problem on the standard Linux machine).